# Unity3d save texture3d on runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, save, assets

I am looking for a way to save my texture3D inside the Unity application on runtime. In my programm I import multiple PNGs and put them together to one texture3D. To save this and load it faster I want to save and load this texture3D rather than importing the images every start again. Before I used AssetDatabase, which worked pretty well. But of course I want to build my program and run into the problems. I don't find any way to avoid the AssetDatabase, all posts only suggest using it. How is it helpful when it cannot be used on runtime? How do you save your assets and game states?

Best regards

Comment: Texture3D does not have a native format. That's why they "can only be created from script."

Comment: You can only create actual image files via e.g. `EncodeToJpg` and write the retrieved `byte[]` to a file on runtime.

Comment: But I can create assets out of texture3D, at least with the UnityEditor class and AssetDatabase. Is there now workaround to create and save assets at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @derHugo.

The answer is, that anything you want to save during runtime you have to convert to a byte[] array and save it with `File.WriteAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes);` -> https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.File.WriteAllBytes.html

Also the 3D data from a texture3D you can extract and encode and decode into and from a byte[] array which you can save and read.

I didn't use EncodeToJpg, I only needed to read the images in order of height and sort their color values.